# How to compile multiple files with Coliru?

Tags: c, compilation, coliru

Tomorrow I have a test for a company. My files must be easy to compile with Coliru (web compiler) : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

But here is my problem : "How do I use multiples files in Coliru ?" I read the Q&A but didn't succeed to do it.

Here is the program I wanted to test :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//MyLibraries
#include "Addition.c"
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    Addition();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And this is my "Addition.c" file :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void Addition(int a, int b);

void Addition(int a, int b)
{
    printf("%d", (a + b));
}
```

If somebody can explain to me how to compile multiple files with Coliru, it'll be awesome. Thx

Comment: Write to them in the command.

Comment: There's some stuff in the help page. Yes, that's well hidden.

Answer (score 0):

There's [this comment](https://github.com/StackedCrooked/coliru/issues/5#issuecomment-535681028) in the Coliru issue tracker that suggests the following way.

- Choose a header that contains the filename, e.g. `==> Makefile <==`
- Put such headers into each file
- Concatenate the files
- After putting the resulting code (which is assumed to be in `main.cpp` by Coliru) into the source field, use the following build command (I'm copying it here with the comment from the link, for attribution):

```sh
# Here is a cool technique to use Coliru for small "Makefile projects":
# (No need to say "thanks" but if you feel inclined: coliru [at] tbfe.de)
pr -ti main.cpp|awk '/==> [^ ]+ <==/ {f=$2;next} {print>>f}' && make
```

How this script works:

- `pr -ti` converts 8-chars into tabs (for the `Makefile` to be syntactically valid)
- `awk ...` finds the header line, extracts the filename from it and then writes everything until the next header into corresponding file
- `make` simply works on the resulting set of files.

How to convert your project to this format:

```sh
for file in *; do printf "==> $file <==\n" >> main.cpp; cat "$file" >> main.cpp; done
```

**Note**: make sure that your project doesn't have a file named `main.cpp`, or you'll need to adjust the build script (and the generator script).

The [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7569e58e2ca6bad) is taken from the same link above.